# Can't boot Windows after installing Linux

Tags: linux, windows-xp, boot, lilo

I have a partition /dev/sdb1, where my old Windows XP resides. All the files are there intact and I can see them, mounting the disk from Linux. Linux is on /dev/sdb2. But when I choose Windows in LILO prompt, it doesn't load.

I have the following lilo.conf:

```
boot = /dev/sdb
# Linux bootable partition config begins
image = /boot/vmlinuz
  root = /dev/sdb2
  label = Linux
  read-only  # Partitions should be mounted read-only for checking
# Linux bootable partition config ends
# Windows bootable partition config begins
  other = /dev/sdb1
  label = Windows
  table = /dev/sdb
# Windows bootable partition config ends
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: What does happen when you select the windows partition?

Comment: It says: "booting Windows". And hangs.

Comment: I have a suspicion, that I have corrupted MBR. Cause I ordered LILO to be installed into disk MBR, where Windows was sitting previously.

Comment: You can check if that's the problem - try these instructions: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-installation-40/slackwares-lilo-overwrite-xps-mbr-615909/ - if they fix things, you know what's what :)

Comment: Whenever this has happened to me, using the 'fix mbr' option from the Windows installation disc and then restoring the dual-boot bootloader has resolved the issue.

Comment: I would just repair the MBR.

Comment: Thx for help everyone. I did it from Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it directly from Linux Slackware 14.0 without Windows CD-ROM. I did this:

1. Installed ms-sys
2. Ran:

   ms-sys -m /dev/hdb

This restores Windows XP MBR. Then:

```
lilo /dev/hdc
```

Installing lilo to another drive /dev/hdc. Then set in BIOS to boot from hdc and ran Windows from LILO. It worked.